# Declaring integers array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, integer, int

Is there an effective way to declare a very big matrix (let's say 40.000.000x10) of integers in Matlab?
If I do it like this:

```
var=uint8(zeros(40000000,10));
```

It works very well in command window.
But the same code works much worse in function! If I do this somewhere in the function, it firstly creates a 40.000.000x10 matrix of doubles and then converts it to 8-bit integers matrix. I would prefer if it was created as integer matrix from the very begin, as in commands window. I have to work with even bigger matrices and I ran out of RAM when it initializes such matrix of doubles (although there would be enough memory if it initialized the matrix as integers). And I don't really need doubles here, all numbers are in range 0:100.
Hope you understood the problem :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: [MATLAB: uint8](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html)

```
var = zeroes(40000000,10, 'uint8')
```

Comment: Yes, this one works as it should! Thanks! I somehow missed that part :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this, which is more efficient.

`var = zeros(40000000, 10, 'uint8');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a bit tricky and save a small amount of time, you can allocate your array of `uint8` zeros this way:

```
var(40000000,10) = uint8(0);
```

See [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/) for some details on this type of preallocation. Be careful with this scheme. If you allocate `var` as one size and then allocate it again without clearing it as a smaller size array using this method, the size won't actually change and the data won't be zeroed out. Essentially, this scheme is only good if the array (`var` here) doesn't exist yet.